# How to use Java Applet in AngularJS client

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, applet

I am trying to use  my Cryptographic java class in the client side of application. I am trying to use Applet for that purpose. It depends only on **java.security** and **java.io**.

**Applet:**

```
package com.MVC.Functionalities.encryption;

import java.applet.Applet;

public class SecurityApplet extends Applet {
    public SecurityService getSecurityService(){
        return new SecurityService();
   }

}
```

I would like only to invoke `getSecurityServcie()` method inside my javascript code.
Unfortunately I am not able to find any tutorials about what files are needed and how to attach them run this service. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: What's the purpose? Is it for yourself or do you want this to be used by some user? If it has to run it on a users browser, you have to look for a different solution. Almost every browser nowadays blocks the java-plugin (by default), if the user even has Java installed. You cannot expect the user to install additional software and change browser config just to use your website.

Comment: Hi, I want to create public/private key pair on client side. Public key will be used to encrypt secretKey on server side. When it will needed, decrypted key will be sent to client, who will use private key to decrypt it and to send it back.

Comment: but is it for you or for others to use? If it is for others (as I assume) you can't use Java at all, because nobody has it and even if, it is most likely blocked. Google for a proper crypto library in JS, without Java.

Comment: Thanks for answer, good to know. The problem Is i need a proper crypto library for both java and javascript,

Comment: What you do on your server is your buisness, so is your computer. But these days you cannot rely on any plugin to be installed in the browser of you user. Maybe [Unity](//unity3d.com) (C#) if you build games, but for anything else you should find *(or build)* a JS solution. One of the first [hits on google](//www.google.com/search?q=js+crypto) for "JS crypto": [List of JavaScript Crypto libraries](//gist.github.com/jo/8619441)